Next.js 14 with next-intl and subdomain implementation
I have Next.js 14 app which i implemented next-intl.
Here is my middleware code :
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { localePrefix, locales } from "Services/localization/navigation";

export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const handleI18nRouting = createMiddleware({
    locales,
    localePrefix,
    defaultLocale: "en",
    localeDetection: false,
  });

  const response = handleI18nRouting(request);

  const { nextUrl } = request;
  const hostname = request.headers.get("host") || "";
  const subdomain =
    hostname.split(".").length >= 2 ? hostname.split(".")[0] : "";

  if (subdomain) {
    nextUrl.searchParams.set("subdomain", subdomain);
  }

  NextResponse.rewrite(nextUrl);

  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!_next|.*\\..*).*)"],
};

now i want to add subdomain in next.js searchParams in my middleware how can i return both NextResponse.rewrite(nextUrl); and response so that i keep the functionality of next-intl and also get subdomain?
i tried code above and each of them separately works but not together
